# How to set the connection string for SQL Server using EF Core with .Net Core 3.1 using a Mac

Tags: c#, command-line, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-mac, .net-core-3.1

When I run this command

```
dotnet ef database update
```

I get the following error:

> Build started...
>
> Build succeeded.
>
> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, String connectionString, Action`1 sqlServerOptionsAction)
>
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer[TContext](DbContextOptionsBuilder`1 optionsBuilder, String connectionString, Action`1 sqlServerOptionsAction)
>
>   at Azure.UserDataContextFactory.CreateDbContext(String[] args)
>
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContextFromFactory(Type factory)
>
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass13_1.<FindContextTypes>b__9()
>
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String contextType)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
>
> Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')

I am using Visual Studio for Mac and using terminal to run the commands. But unable to connect to my SQL Server database. Can anyone help?